# HTTP Client (Declarative or Low Level) could not access internet from the pod [Micronaut 1.1.4]

Tags: docker, kubernetes, micronaut

I built a simple micronaut project, which fetch Bintray like show in this [tutorial](https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-http-client/guide/index.html).

When i access the container like this:

```
kubectl exec -it -n namespace demo sh
```

i can then execute a curl looking like this

```
curl -x proxy:port https://bintray.com/path
```

And it's work.
Unfortunately the client inside my application calling the same url cannot succeed.

**MyController.java**

```
...
@Client("https://bintray.com/path/")
@Inject
RxHttpClient myclient;
...
```

**application-k8s.yml**

```
micronaut:
  http:
    client:
      proxy-address: proxy:port
      proxy-type: HTTP
```

While running test and testing on my local machine all is working.

But on Kubernetes i have the error :

```
io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler
io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler: 
Unexpected error occurred: Connect Error: bintray.com : System error
```

**Edit 1**

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9:jdk-11.0.1.13-alpine-slim
COPY target/demo*.jar demo.jar
ENV VERSION="v1.0"
CMD java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -noverify ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar demo.jar
```

**configmap.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: demo-configmap
  labels:
    app: demo
    release: v1.0
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-deployment
  labels:
    app: demo
    release: v1.0
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
      release: v1.0
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo
        release: v1.0
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: demo
          image: demo:v1.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 6
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 3
            periodSeconds: 5
```

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  labels:
    app: demo
    release: v1.0
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: PathPrefixStrip
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: demo
              servicePort: 8080
            path: /demo
```

**networkpolicy.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: demo-policy
  labels:
    app: demo
    release: v1.0
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
      release: v1.0
  ingress:
    - ports:
        - port: 8080
          protocol: TCP
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo-service
  labels:
    app: demo
    release: v1.0
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: demo
    release: v1.0
```

My question is to know what is the right configuration to make a micronaut work on kubernetes?

Is there any tutorial or an extended documentation about how to configure Micronaut for K8s?

Comment: Where is your kubernetes cluster running? In the cloud? Or is it something like minikube?

Comment: the kubernetes cluster run into a private cloud.

Comment: They could have blocked access from the private cloud to the outside world, hence why I was asking. Can you access the configuration of the private cloud?

Comment: As a test, you can run Minikube locally and see if you can connect with the internet from the pod (which should be the case).

Comment: I run a test on minikube and it's works. Unfortunately not on the private cloud. Which configuration did you mean? I can run configMap.yaml, pod.yaml and so on.

Comment: By the way i do access the outside world when i run curl for example.

Comment: Yeah that is true. What is the proxy in this case? It might be a good idea to include the configmap.yaml and the pod.yaml

Comment: Ok. Let me add the configmap right now! thx

Comment: DId not know you had network policies. Are you aware of any cluster wide network policies, e.g. Cluster wide block egress?

Comment: Yes they are some Cluster wide block!

Comment: Do you have access to those network policies? You can specify network policies that target the entire namespace/cluster, so that could affect your pod, even though you have a different network policy. Can you check if that is the case>

Comment: I have no access to the network policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Micronaut 1.2 everything seems to work.